# Is there any significance to the patterns of Bifrost Landing sites?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

When Thor arrives on Earth via the Bifrost, a pattern is left (burned?) onto the ground.

The pattern is fairly intricate, and does not appear to be random. However, the pattern seems to change from site to site, or possibly use to use.

Is there any significance to the designs, or logic to them?

A landing site from the first movie:

[image: Thor landing site]

A landing site from the second movie:

[image: Thor 2 landing site]

Another Landing site:
[image: Thor landing site]

Comment: They are in the style of celtic/viking knots. I had hoped to find a nice Wikipedia page on the subject, but can't find one with a style quite like this.

Comment: The patterns in the 2nd and 3rd appear to be essentially the same, slightly different lines, but same basic design near as I can tell. The first one is kinda hard to really see clearly.

Comment: The second picture isn't a "landing" site, it's a launchpad (since he and Jane were heading the other way)

Comment: "Abutment"?  Bifrost is, after all, a "bridge"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html) for Thor, it's clear that the Bifröst 'landing sites' are branded with Asgardian "runes *from* the bifrost".

I've edited for brevity;

> **33 EXT. BIFROST LANDING SITE (JOTUNHEIM) - DAY 33**
>
> Snow flurries up when the Bifrost hits, as Thor and his band touch
>   down. RUNES from the Bifrost are imprinted on the ice around them.

and

> **111 EXT. BIFROST LANDING SITE (EARTH) - DAY 111**
>
> The Bifrost runes cover the desert sand around them.

### The patterns appear to serve no specific purpose other than to make the landing site look more interesting.

As Visual Effects Supervisor [Jake Morrison](http://www.flickeringmyth.com/2014/01/hammering-away-jake-morrison-talks.html) says;

> They have nano-technology and anti-gravity but instead of making
>   futuristic spaceships they chose to make flying boats, because they
>   like boats; they’re Vikings!

The same principle (of covering their stuff with Norse and Celtic runes) clearly applies to all of their other technology. In the absence of any canon description, we can assume that they're **simply decorative**.

---

Out of universe, similar runes are found on the side of Mjolnir as well as in the designs for the forcefield, boats and other props seen in Thor and Thor 2. These are described by the Director of Thor 2 ([Alan Taylor](http://screenrant.com/thor-2-interview-alan-taylor/)) as simply being

> embedded or drawn from Norse sources and Celtic sources

and are intended to create an obvious visual link between Asgardian culture and ancient Earth culture. Again, there is no special *meaning* to the runes and designs which were evidently selected for their artistic appeal.

[image: Mjolnir Runes]
[image: Loki Prison]

Answer (score -1):

Here is my theory. The patern of the burn is dependant on position of the target location compared to that of the bifrost. Unlike a stargate with set adresses the bifrost must be recalibrated at each use and this pathern is a section of an asgardian star targetin map. And since Asgard is apparantly in an other section of the galaxy cluster they are tracking moving target(it's probably part of heimdall's job to update the area of interest's location.) it's like in star trek with the moving while using the transporter trick but only it's like that every time you use it.

Comment: And interesting theory. Not one supported by what we see on screen though.

Comment: Yeah. Can you support this in any way?