# How long do the Bifrost landing marks stay?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

In almost every instance of the MCU movies, we have seen Thor open the Bi-frost to travel from Midgard to Asgard. When he (or as a matter of fact any Asgardian) does that, there is a circular scorch mark on the ground with some kind of inscriptions in ancient runes (discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50936/is-there-any-significance-to-the-patterns-of-bifrost-landing-sites)).

Do these *markings* stay forever? Or do they vanish after some time?

Comment: They presumably stay as long as it takes for the grass to regrow

Comment: hrm. have we ever seen a landing spot more than once? Maybe the Avengers new facility?

Comment: @KutuluMike yes. in the first movie, Thor, the Warriors three and later even the Destroyer end up at the same landing place.

Comment: @Shreedhar - It was a rather short period of time however between those events if they do indeed disappear over time. I can not remember an example off the top of my head, but I remember at least one instance where the mark seemed to have vanished. Maybe when Thor goes to Earth and returns to Asgard with Jane? That prompts my curiosity of the same question rather often when I view the films as well. - I also dont remember seeing any mark when they travelled to other realms in the films either; just Earth...

Comment: “almost every instance of the MCU movies” — as in, almost every MCU movie? Thor’s not in most of them.

Answer (score 4):

## The marks last however long it takes for the burned ground to erode away, be overgrown, etc.

Let's consider a bit of tangential evidence from *Ant-Man*.  It's really easy to miss, but take a really close look at this frame right here, from the scene where Scott breaks into the Avengers compound:

[image: Wide view of the Avengers compound]
[image: Close-up of the spot in question]

That's the spot where Thor caught the Bifröst away from Earth at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.  Here's that scene for reference:

So just a few weeks to months later, the grass has nearly filled all the way back in.